# Moving and upgrading an iPhoto library

Tags: photos.app, photos, macos

A few months ago I had an external drive with my iPhoto Library for iPhoto 4 on it failed. I was able to recover everything from the drive successfully and continued using the iPhoto library in its new location.

I've recently upgraded to a new computer and thought, I'd be able to just copy my iPhoto Library folder to the new computer, "iPhoto '11" do its upgrade and everything would work smoothly. That has not been the case. iPhoto wouldn't even open the library, so I tried using iPhoto Library Manager to rebuild the library. This helped to rebuild the library with about 1/3 of the photos, but couldn't find the rest because it was looking for them on the drive that had failed. I've tried rebuilding this on both the old and new computers with the same results. I have also tried modifying the **AlbumData.xml** file to reference the correct drive, but it still didn't find the photos.

Is there anything else I can try to get my library transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up hooking up the old drive again, and used iPhoto Library Manager to rebuild the library. It pulled the photos off the old drive and built a new library that appears to be working correctly. I'm not sure why I had to get the old drive involved, but it appears to have worked.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered if the problem is solved !